# setX e setY não funcionam no pane (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, animação, posicionamento, imageview

Estou tendo um problema para setar a posição x e y de uma ImageView em um Pane no JavaFX. É um código em loop e, na primeira vez que o método é chamado, ele seta o objeto img nas coordenadas específicas (últimas duas linhas), mas a partir da segunda vez, o Java passa a ignorar essa posição. Eis o codigo:

```
    private void embarque_para_vagao(){
        int dif, aux, dif2;

        if(Integer.parseInt(nome) <= 4 ){
            aux = Integer.parseInt(nome);
            dif = -40;
            dif2 = 5 - Integer.parseInt(nome);
        }

        else{
            aux = Integer.parseInt(nome)-4; 
            dif = 75;
            dif2 = Integer.parseInt(nome)-1;
        }

        PathTransition entra_fila = new PathTransition();
        entra_fila.setNode(img);
        entra_fila.setDuration( Duration.seconds( TempoEmbarque ) );

        Polyline line = new Polyline(
            60+42*(aux+dif2), -210-42*3,
            60+42*(aux+dif2-vagao.CadeirasOcupadas), -210-42*3,
            60+42*(aux+dif2-vagao.CadeirasOcupadas), -210-42*4
        );
        entra_fila.setPath(line);
        entra_fila.play();
        while(entra_fila.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING){
            System.out.println(entra_fila.getStatus());
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ancVagao.getChildren().add(img);
        });
        img.setX(-188);
        img.setY(-70);
    }
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi você deve estar querendo fazer uma espécie de jogo, movimentando a imagem pela tela. Talvez usando o Canvas isso saia mais fácil. Também me parece que você está adicionando a mesma imagem várias vezes como filha de ancVagao.